# xdotool command works at command line, not in bash script

Tags: bash, command-line, mupdf, xdotool

Why does the command
`xdotool search --class mupdf windowactivate --sync type f]H` 
work in the command line as expected, almost, but not at all in the following script

```
joc(){ # Joy of Cooking, joc [page #, def 823]
  mupdf $HD/ReadBooks/Rombauer/Rombauer-JoyOfCooking_11_823.pdf ${1:-823}
  sleep 1
  eval "xdotool search --class mupdf windowactivate --sync type f]H"
}
```

Note I have tried in the script both with and without quotes, with and without eval, with and without 'search ... --sync'. As far as I can tell the xdotool command has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after starting `mupdf` it doesn't return control to the script until you close it. You have to run it in background using `&` at the end:

```sh
mupdf example.pdf &
sleep 1
xdotool search --class mupdf windowactivate --sync type f]H
```

Comment: Perfect, and how dumb must I be not to have noticed that.